# Printing extra training metrics with Tensorflow Estimator

Tags: logging, machine-learning, tensorflow

Is there a way to let Tensorflow print extra training metrics (e.g. batch accuracy) when using the Estimator API?

One can add summaries and view the result in Tensorboard (see another post), but I was wondering if there is an elegant way to get the scalar summary values printed while training. This already happens for training loss, e.g.:

```
loss = 0.672677, step = 2901 (52.995 sec)
```

but it would be nice to have e.g.

```
loss = 0.672677, accuracy = 0.54678, step = 2901 (52.995 sec)
```

without to much trouble. I am aware that most of the time it is more useful to plot test set accuracy (I am already doing this with a validation monitor), but in this case I am also interested in training batch accuracy.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From what I've read it is not possible to change it by passing parameter.
You can try to do by creating a logging hook and passing it into to estimator run.

In the body of `model_fn` function for your estimator:

```
logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook({"loss" : loss, 
    "accuracy" : accuracy}, every_n_iter=10)

# Rest of the function

return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
    ...params...
    training_hooks = [logging_hook])
```

EDIT:

To see the output you must also set logging verbosity high enough (unless its your default):
`tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)`

Comment: I needed to calculate the accuracy like this: `accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels, predictions=predictions["classes"])` and then pass only the accuracy value (without the accuracy op) like this: `logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook({"loss" : loss, "accuracy" : accuracy[1]}, every_n_iter=10)` in order to make it work.

Comment: Note that you need to pass the whole accuracy (as a tuple) like this: `eval_metric_ops = { "accuracy": accuracy }` `return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)`

Comment: I think it's "accuracy[0]" instead of "accuracy[1]"

Comment: I'm trying this solution, but I actually get a weird error: "Passed <accuracy tensor> should have graph attribute that is equal to current graph". What does it mean?

Comment: Check if your tensors come from the graph part defined in model_fn (not somewhere outside this function)

Comment: incomplete, are loss and accuracy tf.summary things or just tensors? or values?

Comment: !tsveti_iko do we have an example of doing this using the TrainSpec ..

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/summaries_and_tensorboard) to see some graphics of the desired metrics. To do that, add the metric to a TensorFlow summary like this:

```
accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels, predictions=predictions["classes"])
tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy[1])
```

The cool thing when you use the `tf.estimator.Estimator` is that you don't need to add the summaries to a `FileWriter`, since it's done automatically (merging and saving them periodically by default - on average every 100 steps).

Don't forget to change this line as well, based on the `accuracy` parameter you just added:

```
eval_metric_ops = { "accuracy": accuracy }
return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
    mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)
```

In order to see the TensorBoard you need to open a new terminal and type:

```
tensorboard --logdir={$MODEL_DIR}
```

After that you will be able to see the graphics in your browser at `localhost:6006`.

Comment: It's not a direct answer, but I think this works better than filling your terminal with info. In my opinion, Tensorboard is much better for watching metrics than a terminal

Comment: where is this documented? "merged them and saving the 100 steps default"

Comment: How to do this for generic tensors in train? Is "eval_metric_ops" eval as in *not* train or is some other semantic meaning of "eval"?

Comment: What does "eval_metric_ops" do?

Comment: The `eval_metric_ops` is an optional dictionary of metrics, that you can provide to your custom Estimator, so that these metrics will be used in the evaluation - check the documentation here: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/custom_estimators#evaluate