# How to control frequency of loss logging messages when using tf.Estimator

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I'm using TF 1.4.
My question is about tf.estimator.Estimator.

I'd like to control the frequency of the "loss and step" Info messages, like:

```
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.00896569, step = 14901 (14.937 sec)
```

I'm passing a tf.estimator.RunConfig to the Estimator's constructor.  But I don't think there is a parameter to control the "loss and step" messages.

I think the parameter is hard-coded in estimator.py, in the _train_model method:

```
      worker_hooks.extend([
      training.NanTensorHook(estimator_spec.loss),
      training.LoggingTensorHook(
          {
              'loss': estimator_spec.loss,
              'step': global_step_tensor
          },
          every_n_iter=100)
  ])
```

Answer (score 6):

`log_step_count_steps` is supported in tensorflow v1.8: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/RunConfig

Comment: To clarify, you have to pass in a custom `RunConfig` with this property set to the Estimator constructor, `tf.estimator.Estimator(...config=tf.estimator.RunConfig(log_step_count_steps=500))`.

Answer (score 0):

try returning the logging_hook as training_hook param in returned estimator_spec for mode == 'train'
[Printing extra training metrics with Tensorflow Estimator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45353389/printing-extra-training-metrics-with-tensorflow-estimator)

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/619/commits/48603b7faed85753ab905f177cbf4e0c8d1dcb64

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#clone_the_tensorflow_repository

src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38097276/2218905

Comment: I tried your suggestion.  It adds a new log to the existing log hooks.   Unfortunately, it doesn't allow me to replace or adjust the frequency of the default log hook that is added, unconditionally, in estimator.py.

Comment: well the logging is in the C++, so it requires rebuilding from source. so just disable logging (set to 'WARN' or ascending severity) and log another way

Comment: I appreciate your help.  However, it doesn't accomplish my goal.

Comment: see updated with c++ fix when building from source, i havent tried this

Comment: I don't think this is related to the c++ implementation.  As you can see from the original question, the LoggingTensorHook is added in estimator.py.  My complaint is that the user of Estimators has no control over the presence or frequency of the logging.