# Print accuracy when training tf.estimator.DNNClassifier

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am new to tensorflow, using [official tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/custom_estimators) tf.estimator.DNNClassifier and custom estimator to build simple NN to solve classification problem.

While training :

```
dnn_model = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[10,10,10],
                                       feature_columns = my_features_column,
                                       n_classes=5,
                                       optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
                                      )

dnn_model.train(input_fn=train_input_func)
```

It will report loss at specific time as following:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /tmp/tmphwkvj5le/model.ckpt-150
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 150 into /tmp/tmphwkvj5le/model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 133.04277, step = 150
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 115.114
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 128.15938, step = 250 (0.872 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 134.317
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 123.093094, step = 350 (0.743 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 133.573
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 117.80729, step = 450 (0.748 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 135.081
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 114.07168, step = 550 (0.741 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 650 into /tmp/tmphwkvj5le/model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:Loss for final step: 118.19583.
```

I want to print classification accuracy every batch or epoch, likes the log Info in keras:

```
Epoch 1/20
5000/5000 [==============================] - 1s 157us/step - loss: 1.4885 - acc: 0.3276 - val_loss: 1.4397 - val_acc: 0.3620
Epoch 2/20
5000/5000 [==============================] - 0s 66us/step - loss: 1.3792 - acc: 0.3922 - val_loss: 1.4001 - val_acc: 0.3768
.
.
```

How can I find the tutorial on this problem ? All I find were talking about more lower API (tensor, session, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the 'hooks' option in the estimator train.

The particular hook you want to use is this one: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/LoggingTensorHook

A similar problem was solved here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45716062/10498246
where they used the Logging Tensor Hook on a different training function.